# DataTable1.10 expanding beyound div in IE10

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, datatables, internet-explorer-10

I am using [DataTable 1.10](http://datatables.net/) and working with both IE10 and FF33.1. In FF table is showing within div but in IE it is not.

I have bare minimum table with HTML tag.

```
<table id="memberSearchResultTable" class="display" cellspacing="0">
  ..........
</table>
```

When render this table with DataTable in firebug I can see following code

```
<div id="memberSearchResultTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
  ....
  <table class="display dataTable no-footer" id="memberSearchResultTable" 
         role="grid" aria-describedby="memberSearchResultTable_info" 
         style="width: 705px;" cellSpacing="0" jQuery111109173364637806466="256">

    ....
  </table>
  ....
</div>
```

I tried with following CSS as suggested [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200704/how_to_prevent_html_tables_from_becoming_too_wide/)

```
#memberSearchResultTable {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Screenshot

[image: DataTable overflow from div]

Is there a way I can set width of this table to be within the div?

Comment: Can you share a demo that repros the issue? If one exists on the product site that is great; otherwise, you could set one up on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Given the number of things that could cause this, a demo will be needed to debug it.

Comment: I am not able to setup in JSFiddle. But could you tell me why it set width to 705px? I didn't set that value anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, without having access to the full code, I couldn't possibly tell you what is setting it to `705px`. This could be a number of things. I would inspect the element with the F12 Developer Tools and look into the Styles applied for where that width may be coming from.

Comment: In IE it is showing as inline style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer here http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/887/table-width

```
#memberSearchResultTable{
  width: 100% !Important;
}
```